# Do browsers installed on a terminal server behave differently?

Tags: browser

All my coding happens on a terminal server (Windows 2008). My work involves webprogramming.

While testing code from some coworkers within a browser on my terminal server, I realized that the graphical presentation of some objects and colors was not as expected. I asked a college and he told me that

> we do not support terminal server browsers.

He told me to open a browser on my local machine and test the code there.

Is there really a difference between browsers installed on a Terminal Server and browsers installed on a regular desctop machine? If yes are they documented somewhere? I'd would like to know about those differences (if there are any) so I would be able to respect them while developing web applications.

Comment: Are you just seeing a lower color depth?

Comment: @SLaks If I remember correctly, than some objects also appeared "displaced".

Comment: I must admit I don't know neither how cookies and sessions are actually handled... but as i would see it there's no difference. Maybe check which version of the browser is installed though... and be carefull of the compatibility mode if using IE.

Comment: @Aufwind perhaps the browser installed on the terminal server is an older version?

Comment: The difference I know of, is lower bit rate and no shiny 3d effects, since the virtual machine does not have graphics acceleration. 
You can try to activate "desktop experience" feature on server 2008r2. Maybe it works - just a guess

Comment: @Stijn good point. I should have checked that. But I installed the  browsers on the same day on both machines. Chances of a different version are very low.

Comment: So I understand that there should be no differences for the browsers on the TS and on a regular machine in interpreting code except for 3d effects and maybe exotic colors, is this right?

Comment: I have no in depth technical knowledge to back it up, but I am developing sharepoint solutions on a remote machine as you are, and I have never experienced any other differences, like the ones I stated, except IE8 going into compat mode for no reason from time to time.